# Two questions about post_type function in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm making a child theme from this theme ([limo](http://demos.codexcoder.com/#limo_wp)) and I am trying to do two things without success, so here's my questions:

1. How can I get a permalink from a post_type?

As you can see on this demo (the "Our Works" part), I would like to get the link of this post. So you would click on this image/post title and it would open the post page. Using the get_permalink() function nothing happens.

The function is this:

```
function ccr_our_works() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Our works', 'codexcoder' ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Our work', 'codexcoder' ),
    'add_new'             => _x( 'Add New Work', 'codexcoder', 'codexcoder' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Work', 'codexcoder' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Our Work', 'codexcoder' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'New Our Work', 'codexcoder' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Our Work', 'codexcoder' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Our works', 'codexcoder' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No Our works found', 'codexcoder' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Our works found in Trash', 'codexcoder' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Our Work:', 'codexcoder' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Works', 'codexcoder' ),
    );

$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'description'         => 'description',
    'taxonomies'          => array(),
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => null,
    'menu_icon'           => null,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'rewrite'             => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'supports'            => array(
        'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'
        )
    );

   register_post_type( 'work', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'ccr_our_works' );
```

And I'm doing this to get the post link:

```
<!-- Slider items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">

                        <div class="item active">
                            <?php 
                            $loop = new WP_Query('post_type=work&posts_per_page=4');
                            while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                $loop->the_post();
                                ?>  
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <figure>
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <h4><a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                        </figcaption>                           
                                    </figure>   
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- /.active /.item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <?php 
                                $loop = new WP_Query('post_type=work&posts_per_page=4&offset=4');
                                while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                    $loop->the_post();
                                    ?>  
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <figure>
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                            <figcaption>
                                                <h4><a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                            </figcaption>                           
                                        </figure>   
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> <!-- /.active /.item -->

                            </div>  <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
                            <!--/.carousel -->

                        </div> <!-- /#work-slide -->
```

How can I do this?

2. How can I build a page template to join all this post of a specific post_type in one page?

What I tried:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Our Works
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- begin colLeft -->
    <div id="colLeft">


        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_type'  => 'our_works',
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        query_posts($args); 
        ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <div>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more →</a>
            <br><br>


            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
                emm_paginate();
            } ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e('Not found'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- end colleft -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help? I would like to understand how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come on.

1) Permalinks use

```
      <?php the_permalink();?>
```

2) To your page, try this

```
     <?php
     /*
     Template Name: Our Works
     */
    ?>

   <?php get_header(); ?>

   <!-- begin colLeft -->
    <div id="colLeft">


    <?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts(array('paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'posts_per_page'=>5, 'post_type'=>'our_works', 'order' => 'ASC'))?>



    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more →</a>
        <br><br>


        <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
            emm_paginate();
        } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e('Not found'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- end colleft -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that this pagination function is not working. It shows only 5 posts per page, ok. But I have 8 posts, and it only shows the last five posted, with no pagination for access the others. Any idea for fix this?

Comment: Try Before $args add $offset = ( 1 * $paged ) - 1;